# find what the mouse pointer is pointing at

Tags: android, windows, pointers, mouse, interaction

Based on windows system (xp or 7), we can move the mouse pointer to a certain position by programming. My question is: when the mouse pointer is staying over some file icon on the screen, how can I know which file it is? (the file's absolute path)

Question Description: I wanna develop an application on my Android smartphone, which can control the mouse pointer on my PC remotely. The mouse pointer can move according to my gestures on the phone's screen. When I tap on my phone, the mouse pointer just clicks on my PC. Finally, after I select one file on the PC screen (click one time on that file), some special gestures (i.e., draw a circle on the phone screen) can copy this file from my PC to my Android phone. Basically, I need to set up a server on my PC, and communicate with my phone via WiFi or Bluetooth.

But I am stuck on the problem above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't, it is pointing to a pixel.  That the pixel happens to be drawn a program that renders icons to represent files is an implementation detail of that program.  The program itself won't have any problem with it, it knows what it drew and which icon matches what file.  Look into shell extensions if you want to mess with Explorer.

Comment: Perhaps if you described the overall problem you're trying to solve, we can suggest alternatives.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your comment. The mouse control what I wanna do does not belong to any specific program. It is just the normal one. How can I get the path information of one file when the mouse pointer is hovering above its icon? I have no idea with windows programming. Please bear with my poor expression.

Comment: @RaymondChen I just gave some supplement for my problem. I will really appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to figure out what item is under the mouse, why not just let the system tell you? You've already selected the item, so you just need to copy it to the clipboard. (Don't forget, icons can represent virtual content, not just files.)

Alternatively, you can [ask the shell object model for the identity of the focused item](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/20/188696.aspx). It helps a lot that in your case, it's not just the item pointed to by the mouse, but the item *clicked on* by the mouse, since that selects it.

Note that this technique works only if the user selected an item in an Explorer window. It won't help with icons in other programs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the link of the scratch program mentioned in "ask the shell object model for the identity of the focused item" is not available. Would you please show me some simple scratch programs using that function? In fact, I want to use the file path for java programs.

Comment: The program is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/07/23/54576.aspx). Though there really isn't anything interesting in the scratch program. What you want was in the base article. The scratch program is just an excuse to call the function in the article. (And the function in the article isn't even the function you want; it's just a starting point.)